# Django order_by ForeignKey set models

Tags: python, django

I have following django models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=240)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need a QuerySet of comments, ordered first by post, then by date.
But posts must be ordered by its latest comment.

If i could use model methods in QuerySet order_by, it would be like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=240)

    def get_last_comment_date(self):
        return self.comment_set.order_by('-date')[0].date
```

And the ordering, that i needed, could be:

```
Comment.objects.all().order_by('post__get_last_comment_date', '-date')
```

But unfortunately, methods in order_by are not allowed.

Please, help. Can i have such ordering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not use methods in order_by [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) because **they are converted to SQL**.

So, why not **convert get_last_comment_date into a field** ? e.g. using a [signal receiver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/):

```
from django.db.models import signals

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    last_comment_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

def post_last_comment_date(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        last_comment_date = self.comment_set.order_by('-date')[0].date
    except Comment.DoesNotExist:
        return

    if last_comment_date != comment.post.last_comment_date:
        comment.post.last_comment_date = last_comment_date
        comment.post.save()

signals.post_save.connect(post_last_comment_date, sender=Comment)
```

Now, you can: `Comment.objects.order_by('post__last_comment_date', '-date')`

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid, that i will have to add 'last_comment_date' field to Post model and to update it every time, when new comment for specific post occurs. But your solution is much better!

Comment: Oops, looks like i was too fast for previous comment. This solution will update field on every new comment. It works (with some corrections of code, i.e. rename 'self' to 'instance'), but will it raise additional load for data base on every new comment?

Comment: Yes, we're trading 2 (3 in edge cases) queries that happen when a comment is posted, against many queries when they are displayed. Sounds fair to me.