# How to order a queryset using two date fields?

Tags: django, django-queryset

My resumed models :

```
class Article (models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment (models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,related_name='comments')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So what I want is to order my Articles using booth dates.

If I have:

```
Article1.creation_date= 01/01/2014
Article2.creation_date= 01/15/2014
Article3.creation_date= 01/20/2014

(from Article1) Comment1.creation_date= 01/30/2014
(from Article2) Comment2.creation_date= 01/16/2014

* dates are datetimes but for the example...
```

The desired order will be (newest first):

Article1, Article3, Article2

So, what I want is to order Articles by newest but considering their comments datetimes.

with:

```
Article.objects.all().order_by("-creation_date", "-comments__creation_date")
```

I don't get what I need.

Comment: What happens when you swap them over? `.order_by("-comments__creation_date", "-creation_date")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512241/django-order-by-foreignkey-set-models

Comment: @PeteTinkler if I do so, the articles with no commets are at the end.

Comment: @arocks thank! That's the key of the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to add a function to your model that takes the article creation date then compares that date to the newest comment and returns the latest date, then sort by that field something like

```
def date(self):
    newest_comment = Comment.objects.filter(article=self).order_by(-creation_date)[0].creation_date
    if newest_comment > self.creation_date:
        return newest_comment
    else:
        return self.creation_date
last_edit = date(self)
```

Then you can access that date through the query set with Article1.last_edit

Comment: I can't do last_edit = date(self) =>

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
@property
def derniereDate(self):
    derniere_date = self.date_modification if self.date_modification else self.date_creation
    if self.date_dernierMessage and self.date_dernierMessage > derniere_date:
        return self.date_dernierMessage
    else:
        return derniere_date
```

sorted(qs, key=lambda x:x.derniereDate)[::-1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).